# Clear Xcode Compile Warnings

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

The app I'm building is currently out for beta testing, in the meantime I'd like to get rid of the 90+ compile warnings.

Is it just a case of manually going through each warning and correcting it, or is there a quicker/better way? I've reviewed some of the warnings and can't seem to correct them.

[image: Example of Errors]

Comment: Maybe just "opinion" but... I would ***strongly*** suggest you fix them, particularly if your app is already *"out for beta testing"*. From the bit you show in your screen-cap, it looks like you probably have a lot of the same errors, so fixing them shouldn't require "research" for each and every one.

Comment: The vast majority of them were relating to third party libraries, so for them I've put `inhibit_all_warnings!` as it's not strictly relevant to my code.